# Allow me to scroll popup code blocks from anywhere in the code view in the android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a question/answer with a code block that, when expanded needs to be scrolled horizontally, but doesn't fill the popup vertically.
2. Try and scroll by dragging the area below the code text, but within the code block popup.
3. Be sad that it doesn't scroll horizontally.

I'd like it to be draggable by dragging anywhere within the popup, not just where the popup text is.

---

Here is a nice code block to test:

```
public foo()
{
    return "Very long string! Very long string! Very long string! Very long string! Very long string! Very long string! Very long string! Very long string! Very long string! ";
}
```

Comment: This currently works for me. I think what might be happening is that you're trying to scroll on the pop-up rather than on the actual *text* in the pop-up. Can you scroll horizontally if you grab the text and attempt to scroll? This seems like an issue in Android's implementation of WebKit (which is how the code is rendered right now), but I can try to figure out a fix at a later point.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi: That is what happens for me. I can scroll when scrolling on the text itself. My request / bug report is asking for it to work when scrolling anywhere in the popup

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Gotcha. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Though the full screen mode does fix this problem, it isn't obvious enough that full screen mode is possible. There should be some sort of "pop out icon" added to indicate this to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch - this was a bit tricky to fix but it should be in the next release:  v0.1.17

Comment: This bug rose up again in 0.1.50...

Comment: Works on my droid.  What device are you using?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S3

Comment: It works on my S4 - @george can you confirm any regressions?

Comment: This happens in the inline code, which scrolls horizontally for a moment before scrolling the underlying page (to switch between questions and answers).

Comment: Ah - yes.  Touch the code to bring it up in full screen mode.  Scroll will always go to the answers tab.