# Add horizontal scrolling or break lines

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I've just looked at [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12323/5240) with the StackExchange Android App. It looks like this:

[image]

When you look at "Original Solution", you can see a code block that has a very long line. Currently, there is no possibility to read this line. When I click on this block, it pops up, but I still can't read the whole line.

I think there should be horizontal scroll bars when the content can't be displayed. Or at least I should be able to "drag" the text so that I can read the rest.

Comment: No 2 fingers scroll?

Comment: What is a 2 fingers scroll?

Comment: Currently you have to scroll on the code when it pops up. See this bug report: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192416/allow-me-to-scroll-popup-code-blocks-from-anywhere-in-the-code-view-in-the-andro

Comment: 2 fingers scroll? like multitasking zooming in and out?

Comment: OK, I've just seen that I have to be over the long line to be able to scroll. so I guess this feature request can be closed.

Comment: I've not used the app, but many mobile browsers scroll pre-formatted blocks by swiping with two fingers, @Kees. No pinching, but swiping, with two fingers. (Mac OS X uses the same for scrolling. Stack Exchange mobile used that too, but replaced it with wrapping later.)

Comment: @Arjan Ok good to know :)

Comment: But then, moose, the whole block scrolls when you scroll that one long line, I hope? (It's not like you're scrolling only that line then?) Then maybe this feature request should be: make short lines in code blocks trigger scrolling too?

Comment: I think the current solution is better than two finger swipe. But maybe there should be an indication that the line is longer.

Comment: I'm not suggesting two fingers scrolling. But it's weird that you cannot drag the whitespace after short lines, if there's long lines in the same code block? (At least, that's what I understand when you write *"have to be over the long line to be able to scroll"*.)

Comment: Ah, but I guess [Allow me to scroll popup code blocks from anywhere in the code view in the android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192416/allow-me-to-scroll-popup-code-blocks-from-anywhere-in-the-code-view-in-the-andro) asks for the same.

Comment: Okay, [should be fixed now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192416/allow-me-to-scroll-popup-code-blocks-from-anywhere-in-the-code-view-in-the-andro/194525#194525)?

Comment: Yes, it's fixed now!